# How can I fix this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made a function which (have to )change body background image, but it shouldn't work ( although I used it for an other site long time ago and there it do it's job). So here's the code, but I dunno whats wrong:

```
function bgChange()
{
    var totalcount=7;
    var num;
    num = Math.ceil( (Math.random() * totalCount) );
    $('#divID').css("background", "url(kepek/"+num+".jpg)");
    /*document.body.style.background=url(kepek/"+num+".jpg);*/
    setInterval(bgChange(),10000);
}
```

[EDIT]
If helps anything, here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>To infinity... and beyond!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bgchange.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Galaxis útikalauz (nem csak) stopposoknak</h1>
        <div id="left_side">
            <h2>Menü</h2>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="menu_element"><a class="" href="#">menupont</a></li>
                <li class="menu_element"><a class="" href="#">menupont</a></li>
                <li class="menu_element"><a class="" href="#">menupont</a></li>
                <li class="menu_element"><a class="" href="#">menupont</a></li>
                <li class="menu_element"><a class="" href="#">menupont</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main_content" onload="bgChange()">
            <h2>Témacím 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dapibus risus risus, congue tempus turpis dapibus in. Donec posuere, felis non aliquam pulvinar, est ante luctus nunc, vel mollis velit turpis non est. Vivamus ut neque a nulla euismod ultricies in vel lectus. Quisque quis mauris felis. Mauris pellentesque eu ante ac semper. Morbi nec dapibus odio, ut lobortis orci. Vivamus eget sem porta orci condimentum facilisis. Suspendisse id tortor adipiscing, tincidunt diam vitae, lacinia velit. Proin sit amet rhoncus sapien, sed auctor nisl. Donec ullamcorper nibh vel faucibus lacinia. Ut sed faucibus eros, vel molestie dui. Nunc auctor ac nibh vel varius. Integer quis nisi facilisis orci laoreet dictum. <a href="#">Tovább >></a></p>
            <h2>Témacím 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dapibus risus risus, congue tempus turpis dapibus in. Donec posuere, felis non aliquam pulvinar, est ante luctus nunc, vel mollis velit turpis non est. Vivamus ut neque a nulla euismod ultricies in vel lectus. Quisque quis mauris felis. Mauris pellentesque eu ante ac semper. Morbi nec dapibus odio, ut lobortis orci. Vivamus eget sem porta orci condimentum facilisis. Suspendisse id tortor adipiscing, tincidunt diam vitae, lacinia velit. Proin sit amet rhoncus sapien, sed auctor nisl. Donec ullamcorper nibh vel faucibus lacinia. Ut sed faucibus eros, vel molestie dui. Nunc auctor ac nibh vel varius. Integer quis nisi facilisis orci laoreet dictum. <a href="#">Tovább >></a></p>
            <h2>Témacím 3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dapibus risus risus, congue tempus turpis dapibus in. Donec posuere, felis non aliquam pulvinar, est ante luctus nunc, vel mollis velit turpis non est. Vivamus ut neque a nulla euismod ultricies in vel lectus. Quisque quis mauris felis. Mauris pellentesque eu ante ac semper. Morbi nec dapibus odio, ut lobortis orci. Vivamus eget sem porta orci condimentum facilisis. Suspendisse id tortor adipiscing, tincidunt diam vitae, lacinia velit. Proin sit amet rhoncus sapien, sed auctor nisl. Donec ullamcorper nibh vel faucibus lacinia. Ut sed faucibus eros, vel molestie dui. Nunc auctor ac nibh vel varius. Integer quis nisi facilisis orci laoreet dictum. <a href="#">Tovább >></a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="right_side">
            <img src="Me.jpg" alt="Én vagyok" />
            <h4>Ez Injektív!</h4>
            <p>Quisque congue nunc vel bibendum dictum. Curabitur elit ligula, auctor viverra mauris eu, mollis luctus libero. Aliquam vel semper tortor, eu vestibulum risus. Nullam scelerisque malesuada lectus ut fermentum. Phasellus gravida felis ut laoreet mollis. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Soha Művek Zrt.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your html at?

Comment: Do you have an element with the id of `divID`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Lots of things could be wrong. `. Do you have a node with id `divID`, do you have a directory `kepek` with a file named `1.jpg`, etc ??

Comment: `setInterval(bgChange, 10000)` or `setInterval("bgChange()", 10000)`

Comment: yeah, maybe the div id is wrong, but hte others are exists. The only question is, how it works, because I didn't changed the code, and it worked on the other site ( forget me, I hardly can use js)

Comment: @tymeJ - Using the second snippet in your comment, with the string, is considered bad form

Answer (score 4):

The last thing you do, every time you run the function, is to run the function again.

This locks up the event loop so there will never been a repaint of the DOM.

Take the `()` off the end of `bgChange` so that you pass the `bgChange` itself function to `setInterval` instead of the return value (`undefined`) of calling that function.

Then change `setInterval` to `setTimeout` so that you don't say "Every time this function runs, run it again every 10 seconds" since that would increase the number of times the function ran every 10 seconds exponentially.

`setInterval(bgChange(),10000);` should be `setTimeout(bgChange ,10000);`

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to make this happen on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var repeater = setInterval(bgChange, 10000);
  function bgChange(){
    var totalcount=7,
      num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount ),
      target = $('#divID');
    if(target.length)
      target.css("background", "url(kepek/"+num+".jpg)");
    else
      clearInterval(repeater);
  }
});
```

Comment: And if I would like use it on body?

Comment: Edited to fix the typo and actually set the target :)